# SharePointOnlineCredentials throws ComException

Tags: sharepoint, azure, com, office365

I am working with SharePoint online and using Windows Azure to host the process accessing SPO.

We have added a Startup Task to the Azure roles to install http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=35585 . Our first issue was that it would not install because the osFamily was 1 (Server 2008 R2 is a prereq).

We are now seeing this error when trying to instantiate a SharePointOnlineCredentials object.

Application: WaWorkerHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.EnsureInited()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.ManagedIdcrl.LogonIdentity(System.String, System.Security.SecureString)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials..ctor(System.String, System.Security.SecureString)

What could I be doing wrong?

PS. I have got Microsoft.IdentiyModel v3.5 set to Copy local

EDIT: The event log shows the exception before the above exception, the message is below.
From what I can tell this is the sign in helper for MS online.

Source MSOIDSVC.EXE. Message: InitializeSvcAPI failed with hr = 0x80048883

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception. To resolve it :

Connect to http://login.microsoftonline.com in IE with the account that you will use in your app (or app pool) and install the certificate from the page.

It solved my problem.

Hope can help.